# Google Closure Removal Timeline

Tags: openlayers-3

A lot of fantastic work is being done to incrementally remove the dependency on Google Closure.

Has there been a ballpark timeline communicated? Maybe we have a sense of scale? Ie. months vs. years ?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe ask the developers and not random people on Stack Overflow..?

Comment: The OpenLayers website specifically asks that questions get asked here. The only alternative is to raise a ticket, but they ask that those are for bugs.  The tag for this question should make it visible to the OL community who keep an eye on these things.